# error during boost 1.53.0 installation

Tags: boost, bjam

I'm following the steps at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html, but I get the following error in step 3 `./b2 install --prefix=PATH-TO-PREFIX`

```
import error: length of source and target rule name lists don't match!
    source: peek poke record-binding
    target: modules.peek
/usr/users/wammar/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/boost-build.jam:8: in module scope
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.0. The same error happens with boost 1.52.0. The same error happens regardless of whether I cd into `tools/build/v2`.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7212, this is due to a bug in gcc compiler version 4.6.0 which was fixed in 4.6.1 and 4.6.2